# "cabal install ___" breaks previously installed packages

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

I find `cabal`'s behavior when installing packages maddening. For example, running

```
cabal install funsat
```

installed old versions of `array`, `time`, `random`, `quickcheck`, and `bitset`, breaking packages like `monadiccp`, `hoogle`, `heist`, `snap`, etc.

It works to go back and `cabal install monadiccp`, etc., but how can I avoid the default behavior of cabal breaking installed packages? Any reasonable Linux package manager, like `aptitude` or `zypper` would *ask* whether I wanted to break already installed packages, when installing a new package.

Has anyone cooked up a workaround script? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://ivanmiljenovic.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/repeat-after-me-cabal-is-not-a-package-manager/

Comment: @MatveyB.Aksenov, what I got from that page was (a) cabal /= cabal-install, I already knew but don't so much care (b) use the system package manager (c) if you don't have system packages, switch to gentoo. (c) is not really an option for me, unfortunately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend [cabal-dev](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-dev), which maintains a separate set of installed packages for each project you work on. That doesn't solve the bad behaviour of cabal-install in general, but means that such failures are more isolated than they would otherwise be, and allows you to fix them more easily by simply doing `cabal-dev clean && cabal-dev install`.

The added benefit of reproducible builds is also nice.

Admittedly, this isn't a workaround for your specific problem, but it lessens cabal-install pain in general.

---

Building on Daniel Fischer's answer, here's a wrapper for `cabal` that aborts an installation if it would reinstall a package:

```sh
cabal () {
  if [ "$1" = "install" ]; then
    local out=$(command cabal --dry-run -v2 "$@" 2>&1)
    if echo "$out" | egrep -c '\((reinstall|new version)\)' >/dev/null; then
      echo "$out"
      return 1
    fi
  fi
  command cabal "$@"
}
```

YMMV; I've only lightly tested this and it causes an annoying delay at start-up as all the dependencies have to be calculated twice. But it should relieve some tedium if you want to stay on the safe side.

Comment: +1 I did not know about this, thanks... I guess this would be the Haskell equiv of Python's virtualenv.

Comment: great, though for zsh, delete local (and add a reminder how to install anyway -- http://pastebin.com/PGYWqdKA ). it seems to work for the funsat example (stopping installation), and allowed installation of `repa`, which did not break anything. so, thanks!!

Comment: also great to know about `command`, now I can pull out a few hacks of other shell functions.

Answer (score 5):

Workaround: always check with `--dry-run` first. If cabal would reinstall any package, watch out.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known problem (see [this slide deck](http://www.haskell.org/wikiupload/b/b4/HIW2011-Talk-Loeh.pdf), starting with slide 22). The Darcs version of `cabal-install` (`darcs get http://darcs.haskell.org/cabal`) now shows a warning when installing a package will break your system. Example:

```
$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 0.13.3
using version 1.13.3 of the Cabal library
$ cabal install monadiccp
[...]
$ cabal install funsat
Resolving dependencies...
In order, the following would be installed:
mtl-1.1.1.1 (new version)
syb-0.3.6 (new package)
array-0.2.0.0 (new version)
containers-0.2.0.1 (new version)
bimap-0.2.4 (new package)
deepseq-1.2.0.1 (reinstall) changes: array-0.3.0.2 -> 0.2.0.0
fgl-5.4.2.2 (new package)
text-0.11.1.12 (reinstall) changes: array-0.3.0.2 -> 0.2.0.0
parsec-3.1.2 (reinstall) changes: mtl-2.0.1.0 -> 1.1.1.1
parse-dimacs-1.2 (new package)
time-1.1.4 (new version)
random-1.0.0.3 (reinstall) changes: time-1.2.0.3 -> 1.1.4
QuickCheck-1.2.0.1 -base3 (new package)
bitset-0.6 (new package)
funsat-0.6.1 (new package)
cabal: The install plan contains reinstalls which can break your GHC
installation.
You can use the --avoid-reinstalls option to try to avoid this or try
to ghc-pkg unregister the version of the package version to see its effect
on reverse dependencies. If you know what you are doing you can use
the --override-reinstall-check option to override this reinstall check.
```